# Potential mod_rewrite Conflict with Placement of POST Request Protection Code in .htaccess (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post

For added security, I am trying to block non-standard POST requests on my membership-based WordPress site using the following .htaccess code:

```
# Block non-standard POST requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/wp-admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/wp-cron.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/wp-login.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/sign-in/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

The /sign-in/ page is "whitelisted" via the last condition because it is the designated URL that all POST requests are made to by site members when they log in:

[image]

I have discovered that the code only works (i.e., successfully blocks all POST requests that are not whitelisted via the rewrite conditions) when placed within the default WordPress .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Block non-standard POST requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/wp-admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/wp-cron.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/wp-login.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/sign-in/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

However, if the POST-blocking code is placed above or below the WordPress .htaccess code, the /sign-in/ condition does not work. If the code is placed *above* the WordPress default code, POST requests to the /sign-in/ page are blocked via 403 (though interestingly, POST requests to /wp-login.php are not blocked). If the code is placed *below* the WordPress default code, nothing is blocked at all. I have been told (by [Restrict Content Pro](https://restrictcontentpro.com/), the plugin developers) that the login process checks $_POST values, so it wouldn't work if a POST request wasn't actually being made (my initial thought was that somehow the /sign-in/ URL wasn't getting recognized as a POST request).

I've also been told that this is not expected behavior and that the POST-blocking code should work correctly regardless of where it is placed in the .htaccess file. It has been suggested that there could be some unique server configuration that is causing this behavior. However, I've tested the issue on several different Apache servers/hosting accounts (including stripped-down WordPress installations) and am getting the same results.

I would like to understand the reason for this behavior. I imagine it could have something to do with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and how RewriteRules and/or [their flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) are being processed, but I haven't been able to come up with any specific ideas that I can test. I've also checked error logs and even tried enabling [mod_rewrite logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) but haven't found anything of value as far as I can tell.